# Dependency error while uninstalling studio_customization module in odoo enterpeise v14

Tags: dependencies, uninstallation, odoo-14

I've created a model called `x_designs` using studio. When I try to uninstall the program, `studio_customization` throws this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/yash/Workspace/v14/odoo14/odoo/http.py", line 639, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/home/yash/Workspace/v14/odoo14/odoo/http.py", line 315, in _handle_exception
    raise exception.with_traceback(None) from new_cause
ValueError: Field x_designs.display_name cannot find dependency 'x_name' on model 'x_designs'.
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are uninstalling Studio, first you have to remove all customizations made with this tool, or else you can face problems like this, where there's a customization and at the moment of uninstalling it the system doesn't find it